# code: {{block type="core/template" template="page/any.phtml"}} didnt work

Tags: magento2

[image]

given image is my file structure. I want to include any.php into my home page from admin panel. So i use code:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/any.phtml"}}
```

But this code didn't work.

Please help me for solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in cms page,  to call phtml with in cms page.

`{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Class" template="Vendor_Module::file.phtml"}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to add template to cms page

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::page/any.phtml"}}
```

Comment: It shows empty block.